# What does 王室宮内庁を予算ごと回す mean?

Tags: meaning

For context in the story the king is saying how he would love to live "here" (referring to the kingdom that the character speaking is in control of) and she responds with:

> **王室宮内庁を予算ごと回す**のなら検討してあげてもよろしくてよ

I had to google to find out what 王室宮内庁 meant, and I believe its the equivalent of the Imperial Household Agency, in this case an agency that deals with all matters related to the royal family.

I'm a bit confused with regards to what 回す means in this context however. Could someone please help me understand?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your understanding of 王室宮内庁 is fine. In fiction, 宮内庁 is often used as the name of (non-Japanese) agencies related to royal affairs.

The verb 回す has various tricky meanings including "to run (a company)", "to moderate (a conference)", "to make ends meet", "to hand over" and "to assign (a task)". The meaning of 回す depends on what the king's request is, which you did not explain. Probably she is saying either of the following:

- I can think of "it" if you hand over the control of 宮内庁 and its budget to me
- I can think of "it" if you can manage the 宮内庁 and its budget yourself

If you're still in doubt, please share the whole context.