# 母親に叱る役割がまわってきやすいのです。

Tags: meaning

> 母親に叱る役割がまわってきやすいのです。

Can someone explain what the まわってきやすい means in this sentence?
Is it 回って?

My interpretation:
Mothers screaming role turns round and round and is easy? 「やすい」

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's the te-form of 回る. This 回ってくる means "(for a task/role) to come (in turn)".

> #### [回る](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E5%9B%9E%E3%82%8B_%28%E3%81%BE%E3%82%8F%E3%82%8B%29/)
>
> ６ 物事が順に移る。「仕事が―・ってくる」「週単位で当番が―・る」

[The やすい construction](https://nihongokyoshi-net.com/2019/05/02/jlptn4-grammar-yasui/) is also important. Besides, 叱る is not "to scream" but "to scold". (叫ぶ is a different word with a different kanji.)

So:

> 母親に叱る役割がまわってきやすいのです。
>
> (It's that) the role of scolding can easily come to the mother.

A free translation is "In a case like this, it's often the mother's turn to scold (her kid)."

回る/回す has other meanings:

- [meaning of the expression 順調に回る](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/82519/5010)
- [What does "回る" mean in this sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/68142/5010)
- [What does 王室宮内庁を予算ごと回す mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/65691/5010)